# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object UiManager.Update () (at Assets/UiManager.cs:32)

Tags: unity-game-engine, instance

I have created game objects. Is it possible that unity has changed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKzmx.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't set ScoreText variable to an instance in the Unity editor's Inspector.

[Unity VariablesAndTheInspector Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VariablesAndTheInspector.html)